# Changing WP7 application icon on marketplace after submission

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

the last time I updated an app, there wasn't a choice to change the icon that will appear to users in the marketplace.

Should I delete the previous submission and create a new one in order to do that? or there is an easier way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just submit an update. You can change the icon at any time in the content section, just upload a new 300x300px icon.

Comment: That's right. They're updating their site from time to time. Now, the app name is the only thing that you can't change. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to wait then the whole certification process again?

Comment: @zavolokas I would say yes. But you may try to write a note for the tester, that you just changed the icon